# Mysql joining multiple table, where clause issues

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a little problem with my database about getting result with a SQL Query.
I have 5 tables that I want to join with specific join to get all the informations about it.
There is my tables :

**lessons**

- id (int)
- lesson_name (varchar)
- id_class (int)
- id_section (int)

**teachers**

- id (int)
- name (varchar)

**lesson_teacher**

- id (int)
- id_lesson (int)
- id_teacher (int)

**classes**

- id (int)
- classe (varchar)

**sections**

- id (int)
- section (varchar)

The fact is that my lesson can have more than one teacher so I made a 1-n relation table between the two of them.

There is only one class and one section by lesson so I don't have to do a link with a new table.

I guess my way to do is good. When I do a select of informations in my database, everything goes OK, except when I want to use a "WHERE" clause to specify one or more parameters.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT teachers.name, lessons.lesson_name, classes.classe, sections.section FROM lesson_teacher
JOIN teachers ON lesson_teacher.id_teacher = teachers.id
JOIN lesson ON lesson_teacher.id_lesson = lessons.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sections ON lesson.id_section = sections.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN classes ON lesson.id_classe = classes.id
```

I have 4 columns with all my data, my lesson are well displayed and everything works ok.

Why, when I'm using "WHERE" clause, I have no rows in my return ? 
ex:

```
WHERE classes.classe = 'BMMP33'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is causing your `LEFT JOIN` on `classes` to act like an `INNER JOIN` which is probably not the behavior that you want.

Try moving the `WHERE` filter to the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT teachers.name, 
  lessons.lesson_name, 
  classes.classe, 
  sections.section 
FROM lesson_teacher
JOIN teachers 
  ON lesson_teacher.id_teacher = teachers.id
JOIN lesson 
  ON lesson_teacher.id_lesson = lessons.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sections 
  ON lesson.id_section = sections.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN classes 
  ON lesson.id_classe = classes.id 
  AND classes.classe = 'BMMP33'
```

Comment: I change the cours by lessons, my bad, sorry :)

Comment: @Simon no problem as long as you understand what belongs with each column. :)  I edited my answer replacing the `cours` with lesson, hopefully that is correct.

Comment: It doesn't change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN it just forces the same results as an INNER JOIN but requires a lot more effort.

Comment: With your solution, it returns all the data even the on that are not from 'BMMP33' and my columns classes.classe are NULL

Comment: @Simon dumb question but are you sure you have data that matches the `BMMP33` value?

Comment: Yes :) I tried with an other one to test. I had to change the LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN and now It works perfectly !!

Comment: @Simon I am glad you got it figured out. :)